Proof exists $\phi\in B(V)$ s.t $\phi(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_k,v_1'\otimes \cdots\otimes v_k')=\prod \phi_i(v_i,v_i')$.
Let $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ vectorial spaces and $V=V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$. Suppose $\phi_i\in B(V_i)$ for all $1\le i\le k$. Show that exists $\phi\in B(V)$ s.t $\phi(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_k,v_1'\otimes \cdots\otimes v_k')=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^k \phi_i(v_i,v_i')$.  Where $B(V_i)$ are $2-$linears forms.
Try: Define $f:V_1\times \cdots \times V_k\to \Bbb F$ by $f(v_1,\ldots, v_k)=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^k \phi_i(v_i,\cdot)$  and $g:V_1\times\cdots \times V_k$ define by $g(v_1',\cdots,v_k')=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^k\phi_i(\cdot, v_i')$ both are $k$-linear. Then for universal propierty we have exists $\bar{f},\bar{g}$ s.t $$\bar{f}(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_k)=\prod_{i=1}^k \phi_i(v_i,\cdot)\quad \text{and}\quad \bar{g}(v_1'\otimes\cdots\otimes v_k')=\prod_{i=1}^k \phi_i(\cdot,v_i').$$

Define $$\phi(v_1\otimes \cdots\otimes v_k,v_1'\otimes\cdots \otimes v_k')=\prod_{i=1}^k\phi_i(v_i,v_i')$$
exists cause $\bar{f},\bar{g}$ exists for universal propierty and is bilinear for same reason $\bar{f}$ and $\bar{g}$

That last part that how i define $\phi$ i believe that is wrong but i need a better opinion. And if that is wrong i would appreciate some help. Thank yall.

Let $V_1,\ldots,V_k$, $V'_1,\ldots,V'_k$ be vectorial spaces and $V=V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_k$, $V'=V'_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V'_k$. Suppose $\phi_i\in B(V_i, V'i)$ for all $1\le i\le k$. Show that exists $\phi\in B(V,V')$ s.t. $\phi(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_k,v_1'\otimes \cdots\otimes v_k')=\displaystyle \prod{i=1}^k \phi_i(v_i,v_i')$.  Where $B(V_i,V'_i)$ are bilinears forms. Now the same argument, done separatedly on each component, works. You get first the $\bar f$ from the function $f$, then the $\bar g$ (or better $\bar{\bar g}$) from $\bar f$.

@dan_fulea, I don't understand ur idea. Cause the $v_i'$ in the exercise also are in $V_i$. The function $\phi:V\times V$ i don't have any other space $V_i'$. Can u explain. Thanks.

I will give you some general $V'_i$. Show the more general result first, then specialize to the case when for all $i$ we have $V'_i=V_i$.

Oh, yes. Thank u very much. @dan_fulea

This is a good question, useful for the community, good work in presenting the question, please type an answer!

A bilinear form $\phi(v,v')$ can be defined as $f(v)g(v')$ where $f,g$ are linear functionals. Since $v \in V_1\otimes \cdots V_k \cong V_1 \otimes (V_2 \otimes \cdots V_k)$ and $f$ is a linear map, from the universal property of $\otimes$, $f(v)=f(v_1\otimes \bar{v}_1)=\beta(v_1,\bar{v}_1)$. As before define $\beta(v_1,\bar{v}_1)=f_1(v_1)\bar{f}_1(\bar{v}_1)$. Do same for $g(v')$ and repeat until you get $f_1(v_1)g_1(v_1')\ldots f_k(v_k)g_k(v_k')$. Define $\phi_i(v_i,v_i')=f_i(v_i)g_i(v_i')$ to complete the proof.

You are mostly on the right track, but

exists cause $\bar f,\bar g$ exists for universal propierty and is bilinear for same reason $\bar f$ and $\bar g$.

this reasoning makes no sense. It's not clear how you think $\bar f,\bar g$ are related to your $\phi$.
Your $f$ does not produce a scalar. The correct type is $$f : V_1\times\dotsb\times V_k\to\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,\dotsc,V_k;\mathbb K)$$ where $\mathrm{Hom}(V_1,\dotsc,V_k;\mathbb K)$ is the space of $k$-linear functions into $\mathbb K$. But this is fine, as the universal property of the tensor product applies for any codomain. Now there is no need to construct your $g$. We can just take $$\bar f : V_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes V_k \to \mathrm{Hom}(V_1,\dotsc,V_k;\mathbb K)$$ and then for any $X\in V_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes V_k$ we have $$\bar f(X) : V_1\times\dotsb\times V_k \to \mathbb K$$ is multilinear, so we can apply the universal property again, giving us $\phi(X,\cdot)$.

I think if $f(v_1,\ldots, v_k)=\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^k \phi_i(v_i,\cdot)$  then $f: V_1 \times \cdots \times V_k \to {\rm Hom}(V_1',\ldots,V_k';{\mathbb{K}})$.

@TedBlack There is no $V'$ in the question as currently written.

@NicholasTodoroff can u explain how works $\bar{f}(X)$. Cause the domain of $\bar{f}$ is a tensorial product, but after that u put $V_1\times \cdots \times V_k$. Are u define a new function in basis of $\bar{f}$ or what. Thanks.

@JamesA. $\bar f$ and $\bar f(X)$ are two different things. $\bar f$ is a function of a tensor product valued in $k$-linear functions. $\bar f(X)$ is one of those values, which is to say it is a $k$-linear function.

@NicholasTodoroff u say this. Define $\bar{f}(X)(v_1',\ldots,v_k')=(\bar{f}(v_1\otimes\cdots \otimes v_k))(v_1',\ldots,v_k')=\prod_{i=1}^k \phi_i(v_i,v_i')$.? And clearly is multilinear. Y reefer $(f(v))(w)$ like funcional $f(v)$ evaluate in $w$.

@JamesA. I have no idea what you're trying to say or maybe trying to ask, what you wrote is unintelligible to me. The only thing I can say is that the equalities you wrote are correct.
